# Template suggestion doesn't work with a custom menu link (custom route)

Tags: theming, hooks, routes

In a module I have created a custom link by creating a custom route inside the mymodule.routing.file.yml and the mymodule.links.menu.yml file.
In my theme.theme file I have defined a hook_page_alter to add a template suggestion. With the debug mode and in the html code of the custom page, I see the proposed template suggestions.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* page--mycustomtemplate.html.twig
x page.html.twig
```

I have build a new template with this name 'page--mycustomtemplate.html.twig'. After clearing the cache, the new template isn't called, and the default page template is always actived.

Did I forget something?

Comment: Where you placed the template?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you put the template in your module folder and not in a theme?

You need to register the template with something like this in your .module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  $theme['page__mycustomtemplate'] = [
    'template' => 'page--mycustomtemplate',
  ];

    return $theme;
}
```

Comment: Hi Leigh ! I tried to use your code in my custom module without success. The template is placed in the theme and in the module templates directory... Also I add ''base hook' => 'page' in your code without success...

Comment: In my controler, if I add this line : '#theme' => 'page__mycustomtemplate', the template is called from my theme directory. It's a possible solution for the moment. But, in the debug html code, the default page.html.tpl is always mentionned and my custom template don't appears in the template suggestions...